# Decoding request object before use it in an Insert query

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, converting

I want to decode a request object before use it in an insert query.

Request object containes the following JSON body:

```
{
  "device":"887B53",
 "data":"89582c60", 
 "station":"B0A6", 
 "rssi":"-99.00", 
 "time":"1586121398"
}
```

That's the way I solved it:

```
const convert = {
        bin2dec : s => parseInt(s, 2).toString(10),
        bin2hex : s => parseInt(s, 2).toString(16),
        dec2bin : s => parseInt(s, 10).toString(2),
        dec2hex : s => parseInt(s, 10).toString(16),
        hex2bin : s => parseInt(s, 16).toString(2),
        hex2dec : s => parseInt(s, 16).toString(10)
      };

const binnumber = convert.hex2bin(request.payload.data);  

const MSB = binnumber.slice(8, 12);
const LSB = binnumber.slice(18, 24); 
const LSB_MSB = convert.bin2dec(MSB.concat(LSB));
const number1 = (LSB_MSB-200)/8 ;

const hum = convert.bin2dec(binnumber.slice(24, 32));
const number2 =  hum * 0.5

const MSB2 = binnumber.slice(0, 1);
const LSB2 = binnumber.slice(8, 12); 
const LSB_MSB2 = convert.bin2dec(MSB2.concat(LSB2));
const battery = LSB_MSB2*0.05*2.7 ;

const device = request.payload.device;
const data = request.payload.data;
const station = request.payload.station;
const rssi = request.payload.rssi;
const time = request.payload.time;
```

The converted Data shows as following:

[image]

It looks really confusing and I'm sure there is a way to solve it cleaner and nicer. Does anywone have a suggestion?

Comment: Code looks quite reasonable to me. You *have* to do some kind of complicated string parsing and number manipulation, there isn't any way around coding that yourself. Only thing I see you can improve on is using destructuring on those last 5 lines instead, `const { device, data, ... } = request.payload`;